# ReferenceError: webpack_base_uri is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, plugins, uri, npm-run

ERROR:

---

Html Webpack Plugin:
Error: webpack://webpack/data:text/javascript,**webpack_public_path**_=***webpack_base_uri***=_htmlWebpackPl  uginPublicPath;?:2
**webpack_require**.p = **webpack_base_uri** = htmlWebpackPluginPublicPath;
^

***ReferenceError: **webpack_base_uri** is not defined***

- javascript,**webpack_public_path**_=***webpack_base_uri***=*htmlWebpackPluginPublicPath;?:2 eval
  webpack://webpack/data:text/javascript,**webpack_public_path***=***webpack_base_uri***=_htmlWebpackPluginP    ublicPath;?:2:46
- index.html:30 Object.data:text/javascript,**webpack_public_path** = **webpack_base_uri** = htmlWebpackPlug    inPublicPath;
  C:/Users/Ymtx/Desktop/vue/webpack/src/index.html:30:1
- index.html:53 **webpack_require**
  C:/Users/Ymtx/Desktop/vue/webpack/src/index.html:53:41

---

I didn't know why it was happended,and i have read many blog,but there were few blog about it.I do want to do with it.Please help me.

### code ↓

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template:'./src/index.html',
    filename:'index.html',
})

module.exports = {
mode:"development",

entry:path.join(__dirname,'./src/index.js'),
output:{
    path:path.join(__dirname,'./dist'),
    
    filename:'bundle.js'    
 },
 plugins:[htmlPlugin]
```

}

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --host --127.0.0.1 --port 8888"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This issue is because of `html-webpack-plugin` it currently asks for a peer of `"webpack": "^5.20.0"`
but `__webpack_base_uri__` was added in **5.21.0**.

https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__webpack_base_uri__-webpack-specific

To quick fix you can put into your **webpack.config.js** on the top
`__webpack_base_uri__ = 'http://localhost:8081';`

Nota: the **port** is where your devServer will be provided

Answer (score 0):

Try to add plugin in webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
],
```

Comment: plugins: [
        htmlPlugin,
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ]                                is this right ?

Comment: But I still seem to have failed.